# How to calculate average tenure of a worker in a factory

Tags: statistics

I have tenure data for active and inactive workers of factory. For calculating the average what data should i consider active or inactive??

If i consider active workers
Average tenure = sum of numbers of years completed by active workers / total number of active workers 
I get 3.5 years as average number.

Is this a correct method? Because this is an on going event. Some might have recently joined the factory so their tenure will be from 0 to 0.9 years... this might pull the average down. Please let me know how to calculate average for an ongoing event??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This is a great question, but it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. The short answer is that this is a so-called time to event or survival problem; you want to construct an estimate of the distribution of worker tenure given both definite observations and censored (i.e. you know it is greater than current tenure) observations, then compute the mean value of that distribution. Good luck and have fun.